# iptables + postfix cant send email

Tags: debian, iptables, postfix, firewall

Recently my host provider sent me a letter about some sort of attack from my server. I'm not into security so i found some tutorial and closed all unused ports with iptables.

Here is my iptables listing:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssmtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3s 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imap2 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imaps 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www state NEW 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain state NEW 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain state NEW 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:smtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ssmtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:pop3 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:pop3s 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:imap2 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:imaps 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ftp
```

For some reason attack stopped, but i can no longer send emails.

-P OUTPUT ACCEPT works, but its not an option for me.

Need help ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ACCEPT`ing outbound mail connections, you need to do so for `dpt:smtp`. The source port of outbound mail connections is randomized, it is not the `smtp` port.

More importantly, however, you need to figure out what was causing the attack, and if your system was compromised, you need to reinstall it to ensure the compromise does not remain available to the intruder.

Comment: Thank you so much. dpt:smtp fixed it. You are my hero for ever and ever and ever